# Extjs how to properly return a success msg with more data php

Tags: php, extjs, crud

I'm having some issues with the return of my back-end.

What I want to do is: I'm looking for some data in my server then I want to return this data with the 'success' response. Problem is, I don't know why, but my grid displays an extra row, with no data in it.

Am I doing this right?

```
$array[] = array(
        "success" => "true"
    );
while($q = $conMy->nextOcorrencia($busca))
{
    $array[] = array(
            "codigo"        => $q['codigo'],
            "codusuario"    => $q['codusuario'],
            "nome"          => $q['nome'],
            "key"           => $q['key'],
            "secret"        => $q['secret'],
            "lastip"        => $q['lastip'],
            "last_update"   => $q['last_update'],
            "url_input"     => $q['url_input'],
            "output_size"   => $q['output_size'],
            "output_card"   => $q['output_card'],
            "next_command"  => $q['next_command']
        );
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know without seeing your JS, but it's probably because your loop is outputting a row for the "success" part.

I'd suggest doing this:

```
$array= array(
    "success" => "true",
    "data" => array()
);

while($q = $conMy->nextOcorrencia($busca)) {
$array['data'][] = array(
        "codigo"        => $q['codigo'],
        "codusuario"    => $q['codusuario'],
        ....
```

Then only loop through `data.data` in the JS